# type is void (return;)

Tags: java, return, void

I just want to know what this codes lack. What I want to happen is that I want this return again to the top and ask again for a new number.

I tried the return user; (as you can see) but it keeps on saying it's void.
Thank you if you'll help!

```
import java.io.*;

class For {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int user;

        System.out.print("Insert number: ");
        user = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for (user = user; user >=10; user++) {
            System.out.println("User: " + user);
            return user;    //this
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In public static void main change void to int. Though I think you're looking to print out user?

Comment: @Philip You can't change `void` to `int`.  Java requires that the `main` method be `void`.  (The class will compile, but you cannot run the program.)

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I'm more familiar with c.

Comment: you need to initialize the user variable.
in your for loop you just assign it to itself, initialize it with 0 or whatever you need.
`for (user = 0; user < 10; user++) {`

Comment: `return` means to return from (i.e. leave) the _method_ you're in, which is `main`.  You can't just use `return` to mean "return to some other point in the program".  I hate to be harsh, but if you're trying to program by guessing, that doesn't work--you need to find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the input inside your loop, like:

```
for (int user = 0; user < 10; user++) {
  System.out.print("Insert number: ");
  int no = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

  System.out.println("number: " + no);
}
```

also you have error in your loop, the condition should be variable < 10 and when it reach 10 it will become false so the loop exit

also insid your loop don't change the counter variable otherwise it will change your loop behivor

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement does not imply any kind of loop: it exits from the method by returning some value, and this is absolutely not what you want if you are trying to do a loop.

Instead you must include in the for loop the input-request to the user, and remove the `return` statement. Moreover you have to modify the start and end condition of the loop, in a way to start from value `user=0;`, until `user<=10`, by incrementing by one the value for each iteration `user++`. Summarizing in this way:

```
for (user = 0; user <=10; user++) {
   System.out.print("Insert number: ");
   user = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
   System.out.println("User: " + user);
}
```

Comment: this will effect the loop index, try to add 20 when you insert number and the loop will stop direclty

Comment: @WajdyEssam you are right, but I tried to modify as less as possible the OP code: I modified the loop condition in a way that it will run at least once. Maybe it is what the OP want: request to input an integer greater than 10 to exit (ok then the user++; does not make sense)

Comment: A better option is to use `while` or `do-while` to repeat this behavior until certain condition is met...

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the method to return `void` but you're trying to return an `int`. This is a direct compiler error. When you want/need to fulfill an action and repeat this until a condition is met, use `while` or `do-while` bucle statement:

```
class For {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int user = 1;

        System.out.print("Insert number. Insert zero or less to exit.");
        user = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        //start here
        while (user > 0) {
            //for (user = user; user <=10; user++) {
            System.out.println("User: " + user);
            //return user; //this
            System.out.print("Insert number. Insert zero or less to exit.");
            user = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello! this worked too. i'll use this method too aside from for. thank you!